# How do I override the style background color?

Tags: html, css, xml

I was doing this xsl file and was trying to create a weather where the top header need to have a different color than the background color but the style color keeps overriding the given color instead. Is there a way to rectify this issue?

```
<style> <!--background color of blue and green-->

        tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue; }
        
        tbody>tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green; }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> <xsl:value-of select="@qLocation"/> 
          [<xsl:value-of select="@qTime"/>] </h1>


    <table border="1" style="border:1px solid black;">
        <tr >  
            <th style="background-color:orange">Date</th> <!--this color should appear as orange but is overridden by the style-->
            <th>Weather data</th>
            <th>Highest</th>
            <th>Lowest</th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/pXTb63h

Comment: Yeah, Like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was referring to `th` tags in the css. You specified like this:

```
tbody>tr:nth-child
```

And it was necessary like this:

```
tbody>tr th:nth-child
```

The `tbody` tag was also missing in your html structure.

```css
tbody>tr th:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue; }
        
tbody>tr th:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green; }
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>  
            <th style="background-color: orange">Date</th>
            <th>Weather data</th>
            <th>Highest</th>
            <th>Lowest</th>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not realize that I missed the tbody tag.

Comment: You also missed the `th` tag in the css call `tbody>tr th:nth-child`. Happy to help :)